# Is there a way to stop incrementing rows at n when the primary key is set to AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want only  6400 number of rows in my `newtable`. How do I do this?

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `newtable` (
    ID_NT int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: 6400 is oddly specific, are you sure you auto increment is appropriate?

Comment: Create a table with a date modified timestamp. Populate it with the correct number of rows. Then only execute updates.

Comment: Are you saying that your table should not be allowed to hold more than 6,400 rows?  Or are you saying that you want to insert exactly 6,400 rows?

Comment: I am saying the table should not be allowed to hold more than 6,4000 rows.

Comment: @Strawberry, how would that look like? I do not follow

Comment: @DeadZone I want to inerst EXACTLY 6,400 rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger on your table. This works of course only if you don't delete rows

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER InsertPreventTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE idcount INT;
set idcount = ( select count(*) from id where request = new.request );
IF idcount> 6400
THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You can not insert record';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And you have ti change yourtable and id ti fit to your needs

Updates to with count rows, that fits the request better